# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message with Discord embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My code is the following:

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
client.on("message", function (message) {


    // inside a command, event listener, etc.
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    return;
```

But it's giving the following error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/908380877506089000/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

It should not do errors, it's code from the original Discord.js documentation: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html , but it does.
I am running the latest version of Discord.JS (13.3.1); and Node.js v16.9.0.

Comment: is `message.channel.send` correct?

Comment: Yes, because if i do `message.channel.send("wownero.org test")` it works.

Comment: afaik. when you try `message.channel.send`, the content must be a string and now, you're passing an object. And this is causing the error.

Comment: @Kid no, it accepts a string or `MessageOptions` which `embeds` is a property of

Comment: On what discord.js version are you?
If you are using 12 sending an embed like this is not correct. Try updating discord.js by running `npm install discord.js@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: For some reasons, `npm install discord.js` wasn't actually installing version 13, but version 12. Thank you, @Christoph Blüm !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how did you get "cannot send an empty message".
But in discord.js v13, it's messageCreate instead of message.
This works for me (it sends the embed when you type "test"):

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {

if (message.content === 'test') {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
   }
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked

Answer (score 0):

**Use for single embed:**

message.channel.send({ embed: embed })

**Or use this for up to 10 embeds per message:**

message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1, embed2, embed3... embed10] })