# Discord.js, can't make discord embeds inside module.exports

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need help with discord.js. I can't use discord embeds inside module.exports.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
   name: "quote",
   aliases: ["quote", "quotes"],
   cooldowns: 3000,
   description: "Generates a random quote",
   usage: "To generate a random quote",
   toggleOff: false,
   developersOnly: false,
   userpermissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"],
   botpermissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
   run: async (client, message, args) => {
      const getNextQuote = shuffler(quotes);
      const random  = getNextQuote();
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('FF0000')
        .setImage(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setTitle("This is a quote")
        .setDescription("This is quote number")
        message.channel.send(embed);
        
   }
};
```

Every time I run the code I get an error,

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Here says your discordjs version maybe wrong : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005352/discordapierror-cannot-send-an-empty-message-with-discord-embed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Message: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message v.13 (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539920/embed-message-discordapierror-cannot-send-an-empty-message-v-13-discord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor), you should wrap the embed like this:

```js
channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```